# Can a model be used as a source in dbt?

Tags: dbt

I'm asking this question to get feedbacks about when it is necessary to use a dbt model as source in the same dbt project?.

In which scenario is it recommended or not?
In which scenario, we do not have the choice to reuse a model as source?

Thank you!

Comment: _This is not a question, you're initiating a discussion. Please refrain from initiating discussions on StackOverflow._ Why would you wanna use a model as a source anyway?

Comment: Are you trying to reference the model from within itself while building it. If so take a look at this in dbt:- https://docs.getdbt.com/reference/dbt-jinja-functions/this

Answer (score 1):

It's not necessary.

A [source](https://docs.getdbt.com/docs/building-a-dbt-project/using-sources) and a [model](https://docs.getdbt.com/docs/building-a-dbt-project/building-models) are two different things.

There is no good use case to build a model and then create a source on top of that model. Instead, just use the model to directly to maintain model transparency and lineage.

Answer (score 0):

Brad,

How about insert into tablea
Select key from tableb
where key not in(select key from tablea where key is not null)

This is an extremely common pattern when building data warehouses.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).